# Running a web application on UNIX

Tags: java, unix

I have a simple web application based on Java and javascript. I have only used it in Windows OS.

Is it possible to run the server on a unix machine? And access it from other machines?
What server does unix support?

If it is possible, what steps would be involved in doing so?

Current environment:
Application Server: Apache tomcat 
Java Version :JDK 1.6. 
OS: Windows XP

I have no idea about UNIX machines and have not used one before. I am assuming JDK can be installed on the UNIX server. And change of application server should not be an issue.

Comment: What flavor of Unix are you talking about? Does it run a JVM?

Comment: WepApps are portable, but you would need to give much more information to get an answer that can really help you, like what AppServer are you using on Windows?, what Unix server will you be using?, versions of what you have right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Platform Independent feature comes in.

It will run, only thing is your code should not have things specific to OS, like using File path separator like "/" instead use File.separator.

Also, you will need JVM specific to OS ie unix variant.

And access it from other machines? 
Yes, Application deployed on server is accessible from any place in UNIX as well.

What server does unix support?
You can use Tomcat to test (Others based on your need).

what steps would be involved in doing so?
Same as what you did in Windows what you did.